# How can i compare two dates - they should match on day or year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the following dates

```
var date1 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf());
var date2 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf());
```

if i use

```
 if (date1.isSame(date2)) {
      c.log('same')
    } else {
      c.log('not same')
      // They are not on the same day
    }
```

then they will be same.

But how can i match - true when the year is different

```
var date1 = moment(new Date(2029, 4, 17).valueOf());
    var date2 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf());
```

this should give true because they are both on 17 day.Even the year is different.
This should also remain true

```
var date1 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf());
var date2 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf());
```

Comment: format both dates to `dd/mm` format and check for string equality

Comment: Why are you creating your moments like that? There are so many more efficient methods; using just a `Date`: `moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17))`; using an object: `moment({ y:2019, M:4, d:17})`; or simplest of all, an array: `moment(2019, 4, 17)`. All detailed in [the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
var date1 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf()).format('MM/DD');
var date2 = moment(new Date(2019, 4, 17).valueOf()).format('MM/DD');

if  (date1 === date2) 
    console.log('true'); 
else 
     console.log('false');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could compare month and day to check if they're same, no matter the year:

```
if (date1.format('M') ===  date2.format('M') && date1.format('D') ===  date2.format('D'))
    console.log('day and month are the same')
```

EDIT: changed bug in condition

Comment: Both checks are using `format('M')` (Month), one of those should probably be `format('D')`, right? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `month` which is represented by the format token **M** and `day of month` represented by the format token **D** are the same like this

```
if(date1.format('M') === date2.format('M') && date1.format('D') === date2.format('D')){
    // Your code goes here after
}
```

If they are the same that means It's the same day of the same month whatever the year